# Set UITextField placeholder color programmatically

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How to set UITextField place holder color programmatically in swift?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1 - Create an AttributedString with colour you want.
2 - Set this AttributedString to the textfield attributedPlaceholder property

```
let placeholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Some", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30));
textField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder;
self.view.addSubview(textField)
```

From apple documentation

> `var attributedPlaceholder: NSAttributedString!`
>   This property is nil by default. If set, the placeholder string is drawn using a 70% grey color and the remaining style information (except the text color) of the attributed string. Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the placeholder property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting information. Assigning a new value to this property does not affect any other style-related properties of the text field.

Comment: Swift Implementation;
`textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:textField.placeholder!,attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])`

Comment: According to the docs, UITextField ignores the text color provided in attributedPlaceholder https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/attributedPlaceholder

Comment: You should use `let` for their declaration since in this context their references will not be changed. Just a reminder for better swift code. Good answer tho.

Answer (score 2):

```
captionField = UITextField()
captionField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)
var placeHolder = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter caption", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
captionField.attributedPlaceholder = placeHolder
captionField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add alpha value:

```
var placeholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(white: 0.6, alpha: 0.5)])
```